# Are there ways to find representations of matrices given an algebra?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra, matrix-elements, algorithms

Given an equation (or a set of equations) involving matrices, is there an algorithm to find possible representations of these matrices?

For example, we can consider a matrix $A$ such that
$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Now one possible representation could be $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, another could be $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

As another example, we can consider an algebra involving two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $AB=A + B$. Now is it possible to find possible representations of $A$ and $B$? For this particular case, it is known that no finite dimensional representations exist.

But we could consider more general cases involving a larger number of matrices and more equations that they have to satisfy. In that case, are there any general algorithms to find possible representations?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Something like this AB-BA=C, where C is known and you look for A and B ?

Comment: @Eli yes, something like that. Maybe even C is written as a function of A and B.

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought since a lot of physics deals with representations of matrices, like in Quantum Mechanics or QFT, maybe someone might have an idea. But maybe this is not the best place for this question, in hindsight.